# Numbering Issue with matplot R

Tags: r

I am using

```
matplot(data, type = c("b"), col =a ,pch=as.character(0:12))
```

to plot the data of a matrix called data.

The issue is that the parameter `pch=as.character(0:12)` is not working how I would like it. Instead of printing numbers from 0 to 12 it prints number from 0 to 9 and prints the other numbers (10,11,12) as 1's. I know that if I were using the function `plot()` I could solve this issue by using `text()` instead of `points()`. But I would really like to use `matplot()`. Is there a way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Alas, "pch" stands for "plotting character", not "plotting text" so you only get a a single character/symbol. The reason is so you can specify `pch="sSvV"` rather than `pch=c("s","S","v","V")`.

Comment: Isn't `matplot(data, type="b", col=a)` enough?

Comment: Thanks MrFlick. No because I have a 13x13 matrix instead of printing 10,11,12,13 it will replace them by one. How can I solve this?

Comment: Think of it as an opportunity :-) to write a `mattext` function along the lines of `mattext<-function(data,stringlist) for(j in 1:length(stringlist) text(data[j,1],data[j,2],stringlist[[j]])` . Incomplete but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of using `text` to generate multi-character labels, as suggested by @Carl Witthoft:

```
# generate some data
A = matrix(runif(min=0, max=3, n=150), ncol=15, nrow=10)

# add a value each column to have some separation between plotted lines
A = sweep(x=A, MARGIN=2, FUN='+', STATS=1:ncol(A))

# function mattext takes matrix data and names (point labels) and colors for each column 
mattext = function(data, data_names, colors){

    # plot only lines (change type to 'n' to suppress lines and generate empty plot)
    # add `lty=x` with x in 1:6 if you want same lines for all
    matplot(data, pch=NA, type='b', col=colors)

    # add point label for each column
    for (i in 1:ncol(data)){
        text(x=1:nrow(data), y=data[,i], lab=data_names[i], col=colors[i])
    }
}

# run function
mattext(data=A, data_names=1:15, colors=rainbow(15))

# all black
mattext(data=A, data_names=1:15, colors=rep(1,15))
```